# Invalid object name error when trying to execute stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Not sure what the deal is I have the stored procedure named exactly what I am calling however it always gives me this invalid object error. Here is the connection code, the error is thrown on the second to last line there.

```
SqlConnection cnstr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["darconn"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlcmd.Connection = cnstr;
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SetMapping";

String[] pullKodID = bundlelist.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(':');
int kod_id = System.Convert.ToInt32(pullKodID[0]);

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@kod_id", kod_id);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ell_id", courselist.Items[i].Text);
cnstr.Open();
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnstr.Close();
```

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419710/invalid-object-name-sql-server-2008-r2-stored-procedure/23430576#23430576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the stored procedure isn't visible to your code because it was created/owned by a user other than `dbo` or the user specified in your connection string.

Have you tried prefixing the stored procedure name with `dbo`? For example "dbo.SetMapping".

Failing that, use Management Studio/Enterprise Manager to find out who owns the stored procedure and either recreate it as `dbo` or update your code/connection string to use the appropriate user.

Comment: tried dbo, no luck, added user to grant execution on procedure, still no luck, I've accessed stored procedures like this many times before, this is really odd...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I created the stored procedure in the [master] database instead of the one I was supposed to be working on. Probably not your issue, but it is something to take note of.

Answer (score 1):

sql profiler showing anything?

can you execute outside of the context of the app?  from mgt studio or qry analyzer?

Comment: This is my suggestion as well.  Can you execute the sp in Query Analyzer?  Also, usually in an "Invalid object" error, it tells you what the invalid object is.  Is it telling you the name of the SP or the name of an object referenced inside the SP?

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling of the table name(s) in the stored procedure.

When saving a stored procedure it checks the names of the fiels in the tables used, but it's possible to save a stored procedure that uses a table name that doesn't exist (or is misspelled).

Answer (score 1):

Check the stored procedure to see if it is owned by 'dbo' thus the name would be 'dbo.SetMapping' and not something like 'SomeUser.SetMapping'

I would also explicitly specify the 'dbo.' in the name

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "dbo.SetMapping";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong table name inside the procedure, which was why I was getting that error.

Example: There is a table named `test2` in a procedure, with fields from the table `test`. It looked like:

`insert into test2 (fields from test) values`...

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you typed the name correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This one is a long shot, but the common answers are already listed.

Rarely a script can get a different name in the catalog that in the script.  I believe this could cause issues similar to what you are seeing.

The following script will check your db to see if there are items in your catalog that don't match the script.  (You need SQL 2005 or higher for this to work)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Check Syntax of Database Objects
-- Copyrighted (2009).  Free to use as a tool to check your own code or in 
--  any software not sold. All other uses require written permission from Author
-- Author: Stephen Schaff
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Turn on ParseOnly so that we don't actually execute anything.
SET PARSEONLY ON 
GO

-- Create a table to iterate through
declare @ObjectList table (ID_NUM int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1), OBJ_NAME varchar(255), OBJ_TYPE char(2))

-- Get a list of most of the scriptable objects in the DB.
insert into @ObjectList (OBJ_NAME, OBJ_TYPE)
SELECT   name, type
FROM     sysobjects WHERE type in ('P', 'FN', 'IF', 'TF', 'TR', 'V')
order by type, name

-- Var to hold the SQL that we will be syntax checking
declare @SQLToCheckSyntaxFor varchar(max)
-- Var to hold the name of the object we are currently checking
declare @ObjectName varchar(255)
-- Var to hold the type of the object we are currently checking
declare @ObjectType char(2)
-- Var to indicate our current location in iterating through the list of objects
declare @IDNum int
-- Var to indicate the max number of objects we need to iterate through
declare @MaxIDNum int
-- Set the inital value and max value
select  @IDNum = Min(ID_NUM), @MaxIDNum = Max(ID_NUM)
from    @ObjectList

-- Begin iteration
while @IDNum <= @MaxIDNum
begin
  -- Load per iteration values here
  select  @ObjectName = OBJ_NAME, @ObjectType = OBJ_TYPE
  from    @ObjectList
  where   ID_NUM = @IDNum 

  -- Get the text of the db Object (ie create script for the sproc)
  SELECT @SQLToCheckSyntaxFor = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName, @ObjectType))

  begin try
    -- Run the create script (remember that PARSEONLY has been turned on)
    EXECUTE(@SQLToCheckSyntaxFor)
  end try
  begin catch
    -- See if the object name is the same in the script and the catalog (kind of a special error)
    if (ERROR_PROCEDURE() <> @ObjectName)
    begin
      print 'Error in ' + @ObjectName
      print '  The Name in the script is ' + ERROR_PROCEDURE()+ '. (They don''t match)'
    end

  end catch

  -- Setup to iterate to the next item in the table
  select  @IDNum = case
            when Min(ID_NUM) is NULL then @IDNum + 1
            else Min(ID_NUM)
          end  
  from    @ObjectList
  where   ID_NUM > @IDNum

end
-- Turn the ParseOnly back off.
SET PARSEONLY OFF 
GO
```

(As a side note, if you want to see all errors in your db add this after the `if (ERROR_PROCEDURE() <> @ObjectName)` block.)

```
else if (ERROR_MESSAGE() <> 'There is already an object named ''' + ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ''' in the database.')
begin
  -- Report the error that we got.
  print 'Error in ' + ERROR_PROCEDURE()
  print '  ERROR TEXT: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() 
end
```

Comment: Found that script on SQLServerCentral, and it's rubbish. We're migrating from 2000 (compatibility mode) to 2008, and there are some stored procs we found that have invalid column names in ORDER BY statements, and others that select data from tables that don't exist. The 2000 engine doesn't care, it just ignores it. 2008 will still create the procedure regardless of the syntax errors, but it blows up when actually executing them. This syntax checking procedure does NOT find them. Anybody have any alternatives?

Comment: @Cory Larson try my tool checktsql or use the code on my blog http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/checking-ms-sql-server-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Is the database using a case-sensitive collation? If so, is the case in your C# code the same as the case in the database?

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of actual object that it is complaining about ? I have seen the same problem in a stored proc and actually there was no problem with the sproc per se - but due to a typo the name of a table used in the stored proc was wrong (the sproc name had accidentally been pasted in as the table name) so it gave back the Invalid Object name error that matched the sproc name - which was very confusing.

Try changing the sproc name and call it again from your code and see what happens - or try running the sproc directly in SQL Management Studio.

If that doesn't work then be very methodical, divide and conquer - go right back to basics and check everything again end-to-end. Is the connection string correct, what database is it connecting to at runtime, what user id, does the sproc work in Sql management studio on its own etc

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had a completely different problem on .NET 4 that produced the same exception, with little useful information to diagnose it.

I updated several tables in my DBML. I may have re-loaded a stored procedure, but I don't remember doing so.

I was left with the following sproc wrapper in the designer.cs:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetSomeInformation", IsComposable=true)]
public IQueryable<GetSomeInformationResult> GetSomeInformation([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="BigInt")] System.Nullable<long> infoId)
{
    return this.CreateMethodCallQuery<GetSomeInformationResult>(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), infoId);
}
```

`CreateMethodCallQuery` is intended for calling table-valued functions, rather than stored procedures. I'm baffled as to why it would have changed this. I reverted it to use `ExecuteMethodCall`:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetSomeInformation")]
public ISingleResult<GetSomeInformationResult> GetSomeInformation([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="BigInt")] System.Nullable<long> infoId)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), infoId);
    return ((ISingleResult<GetSomeInformationResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

And all is well. Very strange.

UPDATE: This seems to have been caused by Visual Studio deciding a stored procedure was a table-valued function when it was added to the dbml. I've never seen that happen before.

The "IsComposable" flag seems to be the only way it distinguishes between stored procedures and table-values functions. Once I cleared the flag from the Function node in the dbml, Visual Studio generated correct code in the designer file.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your stored procedures actually work outside of .net. If it is working just fine then consider the following...

This error can be misleading if the object referenced works just fine, check other stored procedures you use on the same page for invalid references to the 'object'

The reason is it may be referencing an SQL ERROR inside a **completely separate** broken stored procedure that you're running on the same page.  For instance, say you have a stored procedure to get the contents of a table; if you mistakenly join a *table* with the *stored procedure*(rather than the table the stored procedure was referencing) in another stored procedure on the same page then this error will be thrown. Which can be confusing, since you know that the stored procedure referenced works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

i have got similar problem.
i forgot to write full path to the my actual data base.
so u have to write select *From [your data basename].[dbo].[object name]
in my case in was a table object in practical named database
so,select *from [practical].[dbo].[employee] 
same logic apply for the stored procedures as well

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error occuring each time I tried to insert certain data in an SQL table using ADO.Net .
  Later I discovered a trigger on the table preventing this,when I tried to execute the same command in SQL server directly. So check that too.