# Invalid object name SQL Server 2008 R2 - Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am attempting to alter an existing stored procedure with the command

ALTER 'name_of_stored"procedure'

however the name is highlighted in red noting it is an invalid object. I am able to execute the command successfully however am wanting to know why SQL Server 2008 R2 notes it as an error.[image]

Comment: You are worrying too much about the red line !! . Just write the procedure as it is and click "Execute" everything will work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 however am able to execute it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419570/could-not-find-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008-however-am-able-to-execute-it)

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - I didn't realise it would be treated as a duplicate as I thought it was a different problem since it was displaying the tool tip 'invalid object name'. If you think it is a duplicate, please delete the post. I apologize.

Comment: I think it's the exact same cause, and you already have a resolution, yes? Anyway, I can't delete the post, I can only suggest it be closed as a duplicate. If you want the information to live on, maybe take the additional symptom and add it as further information to the other question.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - No worries. There is no additional symptom and yes I now have a resolution.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's SSMS, not SQL Server.  If it's an error against the database engine you'll know it (it wouldn't execute the command successfully).

#### Solution

You need to refresh the Intellisense cache (Ctrl + Shift + R).  Or you can go to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache.

Comment: Also i often find that SSMS won't detect a database "change" if you change it using `USE DataBaseName` but you need to select it in the dropdown, then refresh IntelliSense.

Comment: user596075: Gentleman. Scholar. Hero....Legend. Step aside, Jon Skeet. Thanks for the solid answer!

Answer (score 12):

Create a stored procedure by using `CREATE PROCEDURE`, not `ALTER PROCEDURE`.

Comment: The question clearly said "I am attempting to alter an existing stored procedure" how is this answer ever voted up

Comment: Actually, this response helped me because I was trying to alter a stored proc that did not exist. Basically, I copied another stored proc (so it said ALTER PROCEDURE _______). When I renamed the proc I forgot to change the ALTER to CREATE. As a result I got the message "Invalid object name...".  I know it's a dumb mistake #NotEnoughSleep.

Answer (score 10):

Intellisense doesn't refresh as quickly as you create new objects.  You need to refresh the cache (Ctrl + Shift + R).  Or, maybe, don't rely on Intellisense and only worry if the execution fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was that I had a select statement from stored proc who's name was similar to table's name, so instead of

```
  select * from Table_Test
```

I was writing this in the stored procedure

```
  select * from Proc_Test --selecting from Stored proc, yikes!!
```

maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and saw an incredible number of possible answers, some quite exotic.  Unfortunately I didn't see this page before finding what worked for me.  I thought I would add this even though I believe it serves the same end as refreshing Intellisense.  I knew I had done my work right because the stored procedure worked correctly in spite of the error so I finally decided it was not a 'real' error.

I exited SSMS and re-entered and the Invalid Object Name error no longer appeared.  I presume that refreshed the Intellisense as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on SQL Server 2014 Express, the stored procedure name value showing this error message

> Invalid object name "SP_NAME"

even if the stored procedure has already been created and executing successfully. But after enable IntelliSense, error was removed and every stored procedure query working fine.

[image]